# How do I find media downloaded to phone from XMBC?

Tags: file-transfer, downloading

I am using XMBC for Android on my HTC One and downloaded a movie to `/storage/sdcard0/Download/`

Where is that going to show up and how do I get to it? Is it possible to download to maybe a cloud or a computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file manager app to access the files in your SD card. There are many good ones out there. **[Androzip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agilesoftresource)** and [Astro file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en) are some of the bests.

If you want to copy files into your PC, [use a USB cable](https://support.google.com/android/answer/1650161?hl=en) and connect your phone. If you want you can use an app like [WiFi File transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransferpro&hl=en) to transfer files using WiFi.